# Problems with conditionalPanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

Hello I have the following issue with conditionalPanel in shiny and I cannot figure out what the problem is (and R throws nou error message). This the critical part of my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(         tabPanel("Ranges",       fluidRow(),
                   column(3, 
                          verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "directory_4", placeholder=TRUE),
                          wellPanel(
                            
                      
                            
                            selectInput(inputId = "Company4",
                                        label= "Company:",
                                        c("xxx", "yyy")
                                        
                                        
                            ),
                            numericInput(inputId = "folder4",
                                         label= "Folder", 
                                         value = 7,
                                         min = 7, 
                                         max = 8,
                                         step = 0.1),
                            
                            
                            numericInput(inputId = "Candidate4",
                                         label= "Candidate",
                                         value = 0, 
                                         min = 0,
                                         max=70,
                                         step = 1),
                            
                            #selectInput(inputId = "rel_abs4",
                            #label = "Relative/Absolute",
                            #c("Relative", "Absolute")),
                            
                            
                            
                            actionButton("goButton4", "Load Data!"),
                            
                            selectInput("plotType", "View",
                                        c("Table", "Histograms")),
                          ),
                   ), 
    
    conditionalPanel(
                                   column(9, 
                                   condition = "input.plotType == 'Table'",
                                   
                                 
                                 # Output: Scatter Plot from the Candidate Files
                                 DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                                 ),
                                 
                                 
                                 conditionalPanel(
                                   
                                   condition = "input.plotType == 'Histograms'",
                                   column(3,
                                   plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")),
                                   
                                   column(3,
                                          plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot1")),
                                   
                                   column(3,
                                          plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot2")),
                                   
                                   
                                   
                                   
                                   
                                   
                                 ),

)
```

The corresponding part in the Server function:

```
Server <- function(Input, Output{      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
         
       
         filter_4 <-  wide_data() %>%
           rename_with(~"Total_Fair_Value_Return_(%)", .cols = "Total_Fair_Value_Return") %>% 
           rename_with(~"Spot_Rate_(%)", .cols = starts_with("Spot_Rate")) %>%
           rename_with(~"Spot_Spread_(%)", .cols = starts_with("Spot_Spread"))
        #filter_3 <- filter(wide_data(), Spot_Rate >= -0.001 & Spot_Rate <= 0.001)
         
       
       })
       
          
          
          output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
          
           
            
            hist(wide_data()$Spot_Rate, breaks = 100, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
                 xlab = "Spot Rate (in %)",
                # ylab = "Number of Paths",
                 main = "Histogram of Spot Rate")
         
          
          
        }) 
          
          output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
            
            
            
            hist(wide_data()$Spot_Spread, breaks = 100, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
                 xlab = "Spot Spread (in %)",
                 #ylab = "Number of Paths",
                 main = "Histogram of Spot Spread")
            
          
            
          }) 
          
          output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
            
            
            
            hist(wide_data()$Total_Fair_Value_Return, breaks = 100, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
                 xlab = "Total Fair Value Return (in %)",
                #ylab = "Number of Paths",
                 main = "Histogram of Total Fair Value Return")
            
            
            
          }) 
        
            
         
      })
```

No matter if Input.plotType is Table or Histograms it only shows me the histograms. Cannot figure out why.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Your `condition = "input.plotType == 'Table'"` is passed as an argument of the `column` function, this is wrong. This is an argument of the `conditionalPanel` function.

Comment: Yeah that was it exactly. Thank you! :)